# How can I fix this Event Log problem?

Tags: debugging, event-log

I keep getting the following event log descriptions for "svcListener" and "svcListener - Prof" in my Event log. Does anyone know where this comes from and how I can fix this?

svcListener

> The description for Event ID ( 0 ) in Source ( svcListener ) cannot be found. 
>   The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer. 
>   You may be able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to retrieve this description; see Help and Support for details. 
>   The following information is part of the event: Cannot perform this operation on a closed dataset.

svcListener - Prof

> The description for Event ID ( 0 ) in Source ( svcListener- Prof ) cannot be found. 
>   The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer. 
>   You may be able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to retrieve this description; see Help and Support for details. 
>   The following information is part of the event: Exception in Oracle Connection- 12560 EOracleEr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like svcListener and svcListener-Prof are trying to write to the event log using an Event Source that does not exist. (or they do not have permissions to create it)

In code, you would do something like this before writing to the event log:

```
if(!EventLog.SourceExists("myService")){EventLog.CreateEventSource("myService","Application");}
```

And you would make sure that the first time "svcListener" ran, it had the permissions necessary to create the Event Source.

To fix it, you can create the source yourself. Just write a short program to do it, like the above, and run it just once from an Admin account.